# Google FormsApp: Change item based on answer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to change item, in my case - checkbox, based on user answer?

For example, I have Date item, where user have to put his/her birthday, and then if user is born on 2001 or later, then add two more options to checkbox item on current or next page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "Multiple choice" or "Choose from a list" and then check "Go to page based on answer". 
Now you need to create a page break and place your extra two options there (Add item > Page break). 
Then after each choice in the original page, you need to select the page you created. 
Therefore when the user selects that choice he will be redirected to the page you just created.